# JUnit testing with GWT and GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, junit

I want to have some JUnit test (created with GWT) to contact a servlet (with GAE calls inside).
When I run the test I get the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.api.NamespaceManager.get(NamespaceManager.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.BaseMemcacheServiceImpl.getEffectiveNamespace(BaseMemcacheServiceImpl.java:65)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.doGet(AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:295)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.contains(AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:283)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.contains(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:44)
    at com.peerkesoftware.etheria.web.server.model.UpdateTimer.<init>(UpdateTimer.java:17)
    at com.peerkesoftware.etheria.web.server.UpdateTimerServlet.<init>(UpdateTimerServlet.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:463)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:829)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

Can someone explain to me why this is happening? And how can I resolve this? Do I need to initialize something before running the test?

I'm using GWT version 2.5.1 and GAE version 1.7.5.

My code can be viewed at [GitHub](https://github.com/peerke/EtheriaWeb).

Comment: Post your code and the line Who throws the exception

Comment: It would be better if you shared which version of GWT/GAE you are using?

Comment: The documentation to create JUnit tests for Google App Engine applications under java is here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

The solution that I used: Create LocalServiceTestHelper and set this up before doing any calls to my servlets. Then all my JUnit tests are green.

Comment: Can you share the source code of `LocalServiceTestHelper`?

Comment: @Halil: com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper (see here for more: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/localunittesting)

Answer (score 2):

The line 101 throwing null pointer exception corresponds to https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/api/NamespaceManager.java

```
Map<String, Object> attributes =ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAttributes();
```

I am guessing your ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment() is returning null.

[Solution](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/1379102):
Edit war/WEB-INF/web.xml  to ApplicationServlet instead of GAEApplicationServlet.

I would like to point out that you unit tests for GWT client side should not be running so deep into server side. You should be using mocking or avoiding server side classes from being invoked from GWT tests to keep the GWT tests faster and client specific.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by changing the GAEApplicationServlet into a ApplicationServlet. I don't use any GAEApplicationServlet. I only use classes derived from HttpServlet.

About your last comment. I know that if I want to create unit tests for the GWT client it should not run so deep into my server side. I agree to that.
But that is not what I want to do here. I want to test my server side and I'm using GWT to access that and verify the results. I want to know for sure that the server side is responding correctly to clients (GWT clients, mobile apps, etc.).