# NullPointerException on NamespaceManager access

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine

What are the reasons that `NamespaceManager.get()` would throw `NullPointerException`.

Can anyone help me identify possible reason(s) that `NamespaceManager` is null and that `get()` will throw NPE?

This is my JUnit test code:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:service/client-config.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyDaoTest {
    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
            new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig()
                .setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(0));          
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        helper.setUp();
    }
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        helper.tearDown();
    }   
    @Test
    public void test() {
    }   
}
```

Basically, `client-config.xml` is configured with `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573365/junit-testing-with-gwt-and-gae

Comment: @whoAmI Yes I have configured LocalServiceTestHelper